# how to write Environment Values to Allure Report in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables, allure

I tried using below code snippet but it is throwing an error while executing TCs. could any one please help me out.

```
import static com.github.automatedowl.tools.AllureEnvironmentWriter.allureEnvironmentWriter;public class SomeTests {    @BeforeSuite
    void setAllureEnvironment() {
        allureEnvironmentWriter(
                ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                        .put("Browser", "Chrome")
                        .put("Browser.Version", "70.0.3538.77")
                        .put("URL", "http://testjs.site88.net")
                        .build(), System.getProperty("user.dir")
                        + "/allure-results/");
    }
```

Imported maven dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.automatedowl</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-environment-writer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

I am using playwright-java framework.
I used this library "allure-environment-writer"(https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/allure-environment-writer#maven-dependencies) but getting some error.

I want to pass Environment Values to allure report like:Browser Name, Environment name (alpha or beta). currently it is showing blank parameter.

[image: Allure report]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `"\\allure-results"` instead of `/allure-results`
Second, you need to check your `allure-results` folder to see if the `environment.xml` file has generated. If not, copy the `environment.xml` file from `target/allure-results/` to `allure-results`

```
File envTarget = new File("allure-results/environment.xml");
File envSrc = new File("target/allure-results/environment.xml");
FileUtils.copyFile(envSrc, envTarget);
```

Hope can help. Or you have already solved the issue. Hope you can share how you did~

Comment: https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/allure-environment-writer#maven-dependencies

Facing issue in this dependency.